# how to send command and its parameters to windows CMD from PHP?

Tags: php, windows, ftp, cmd

I'm using system() function to send CMD commands from PHP. It is working fine with single line command, but I dont know how to pass additional command parameters from PHP.

For example: `cd`, `time` etc. are working fine. but `ftp ftp.myserver.com` command from CMD requires username name password to connect FTP from CMD. how can i pass username and password from PHP script to CMD? the page just keeps loading. may be it is waiting for username input. how can i do that?

How can i send username and password using system() or other similar functions from PHP?

I need to connect to FTP and execute CMD FTP commands from PHP.

Comment: Why can't you simply use http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: there are some issues with built-in ftp extension which are fine using cmd. you may take a look at this question which i could not resolve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382960/cant-download-some-files-with-php-ftp

Comment: You post a link to an unanswered question to prove that there's issues with PHP's FTP extension? Your have problems with it doesn't prove that there are any issues, simply that your code doesn't do what you wanted it to do... please indicate exactly what issues there are

Comment: i'm still looking into this. i just found one issue and i'm not sure if it is PHP issue. after downloading about some images(which are very small in sizes), i just need to reconnect to ftp and continue downloading rest of the images. i dont why it needs to reconnect so quickly. i'm not even sure what's a normal FTP connection. i'm sorry that my previous comment is blaming only php here, not my lack of skills and i should be careful what i say. i'll surely try to find out details of ftp connection,  its requirement and its nature before speaking its issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use instead:

```
ftp_connect($url);
ftp_login($user, $pass);
```

And then follow [this reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) to do whatever you want.